UserDefaults suites ("standard" and "custom") overlapping - the keys appear in both?
I'm currently working on a Swift project where I register default values to two different UserDefaults suites: the standard suite and a custom suite. However, I'm seeing an unexpected (potentially correct) overlap between them. I've tried finding information in the docs about this but couldn't.
Here's a simplified version of my code:

Note: com.domain.custom isn't the app bundle ID, I was only mimicking App Groups reverse domain without the group. and using a domain not the same as my app ID

import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
  init() {
        // Register defaults for standard UserDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
            "standardA": "Standard A value"
        ])

        // Register defaults for custom UserDefaults with suiteName
        if let customUserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.domain.custom") {
            customUserDefaults.register(defaults: [
                "customA": "Custom A value"
            ])
        }

        // Function to print all keys
        func printCustomKeys(for userDefaults: UserDefaults) {
            let allKeys = userDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation()
            print("Custom keys for UserDefaults suite:")
            allKeys.forEach { key, value in
                print("\(key) = \(value)")
            }
        }

        // Usage
        printCustomKeys(for: UserDefaults.standard)
        if let customUserDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "com.domain.custom") {
            printCustomKeys(for: customUserDefaults)
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup { .. }
    }
}

The output I get is:
Custom keys for UserDefaults suite:
AppleLocale = en_AU
standardA = Standard A value
...
customA = Custom A value
...

Custom keys for UserDefaults suite:
customA = Custom A value
standardA = Standard A value
...

I register "standardA" to UserDefaults.standard and "customA" to a custom suite (com.domain.custom). But when I print the keys, I see both "standardA" and "customA" in both suites, even though I expected "standardA" to only exist in the standard suite and "customA" only in the custom suite.
My question: Why are keys from UserDefaults.standard appearing in my custom suite and vice versa?
Is there some behaviour in UserDefaults that I'm misunderstanding? I was under the impression that standard and custom suites should be completely isolated.

Are you sure you intended to use register(defaults:) instead of set here? register adds the dictionary to the registration domain.

@Sweeper I noticed the cross contamination in my main project so started working backwards and this outcome showing it was occurring in register was the first instance of it occurring. I was under the impression register sets up default values for those keys until initialised with a new value.

Yes, but there is only one registrationDomain, shared across everything. Does that answer your question?

Ohh, so it doesn’t matter what suite calls register they all use the same domain? But actually saving the keys are isolated to different plists?

This is because you use register. From the docs,

Adds the contents of the specified dictionary to the registration domain.
If there is no registration domain, one is created using the specified dictionary, and registrationDomain is added to the end of the search list.
The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you need to call this method each time your application starts.

So using register will always add the keys and values to the registration domain. That is the domain with the name UserDefaults.registrationDomain. The UserDefaults object you create will always search the registration domain, in addition to the domain indicated by suitName.
